# Using a SQL Server linked server to get data from an Excel file returns error Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services

I'm trying to use an Excel file as a linked server to import data into SQL Server 2017 Standard using an SSRS report which calls a stored procedure.

I have a test system which, as far as I can see, is configured identically to the live system. In Test, it works perfectly.

But in live...

- the procedure which calls the linked server works when run from SSMS (logged on with Windows auth)
- when the SSRS report is run from the Visual Studio development environment, it works.
- When I run the report from either the SSRS web-based report portal, or from the application where it's intended to run from, it reports this error:

> Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists.*

It's certainly true that no login mapping exists, but that's true in the test system too, and it has no problem.

The Excel file is stored on a network drive, and the linked server uses a UNC name to link to it.

I'm presuming that this has something to do with how the SSRS instance is set up to access Windows files, or the security context in which it runs, but I can't see anywhere that the two instances are different. Both database's use the same server proxy account, both SSRS instances are set up to use the same service account, the same database credential....Neither has an execution account set up...

I've run out of places to look, I think. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are both servers on the same domain?

Comment: Yes - they're both VM's, on the same domain. Good thought.